# Weird column behaviour in responsive email

Tags: responsive-design, outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I'm doing a responsive HTML email template for MailChimp and having some peculiar behaviour in Outlook 2003+ on Windows. The template is responsive, but the issues are experienced in desktop, large screen in Outlook. I'm no newcomer to this, and am normally able to get Outlook 2003+ to play nice with my designs, but have run out of ideas in this case.

To provide context, in my approach to responsiveness I've tried both methods described here  http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/ and neither worked in this instance.

The emails render perfectly in all other mail clients and platforms that I've tested.

You can view the HTML here:

- Rendered HTML - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6136148/mailer-SO.html
- Code as .txt - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6136148/mailer-SO.txt

The two specific issues I'm experiencing are:

1. In Outlook only, the right column in the first 'two-column' section, beginning "Twitterverse" is pushed down a huge amount; I can't work out why. I considered the 'MS Word 1800px page-break' issue, but don't think this is what is happening. Do you?
2. In Outlook only, the three-column 'In Focus' section; the three columns refuse to site inline, regardless of image, table, or td width, when I set it in the HTML, or CSS, or MSOutlook Conditional CSS. Just can't get it to play nice. It seems not to be the padding either.

I am really hoping someone, versed in responsive email design, can import the template to their MailChimp, send a test to themselves in Outlook 2007 or 2013, and let me know what they think.

- Download template ZIP - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6136148/mailer-SO.zip

Please let me know if I've forgotten to mention anything pertinent.  As always, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and the solution is conditional commenting for mso.
You need to add tables only for Outlook to keep the columns inline.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="200">
<![endif]-->
...responsive html code for first column here...
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="200">
<![endif]-->
...responsive html code for second column here...
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="200">
<![endif]-->
...responsive html code for third column here...
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<![endif]-->
```

Example here: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/277-outlook-2007-2010-3-column-issue